# Prove an ideal is coprime to the conductor

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, and $\mathcal O$ be an order in $K$. Let $\mathcal O_K$ be the maximal order in $K$. $\mathfrak f$ is the conductor of $\mathcal O$, i.e. $\mathfrak f=[\mathcal O:\mathcal O_K]$.

Now we have an ideal $A$ of $\mathcal{O}$, and an ideal $B$ of $\mathcal O_K$, such that
$$AB=t\mathcal{O}_K$$
is a non-zero principal ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

> **Claim**: $B+\mathfrak f=\mathcal O_K$.

I can see that $t\in\mathfrak f$. How can we proceed to prove the claim?

**Edit**:
I have seen that this should follow from the $\mathcal O_K$ is Dedekind. I still do not have a complete proof.

**Edit**:
As @user26857 commented, we should assume $A\ne\mathcal{O}$. (Otherwise, $B=\mathfrak{f}$ would be a counterexample as in @Starfall's answer below.)

Is it possible to prove the claim under the additional assumption?

Comment: In the end I've missed the point of this question: isn't obvious that $A=\mathcal O$ leads to a contradiction if you already know that $t\in \mathfrak f$? I'd have expected to fix it, eventually by assuming $A\ne\mathcal O$.

Comment: Yeah, but I still do not know if the claim is true under the additional assumption. Does localization work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Choose $ K = \mathbf Q(i) $, $ \mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[i] $, $ \mathcal O = \mathbf Z[2i] $. Choosing $ B = 2\mathcal O_K $ and $ A = \mathcal O $, we have that $ AB = 2\mathcal O_K $ is principal, but the conductor is the ideal $ \mathfrak f = 2 \mathcal O_K $, and we have

$$ \mathfrak f + B = 2 \mathcal O_K + 2 \mathcal O_K = 2\mathcal O_K \neq \mathcal O_K $$